# Conda Python version

Tags: python-3.x, conda, python-3.8

I'm trying to create a new conda env using python version 3.8.2

When I run `conda create -n envName python=3.8.2` I get the following error message:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.8.2
```

When I try to install `3.8.6`, the env is set up with no problem - but for some reason 3.8.2 doesn't work. How can I install 3.8.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's having this issue with ARM-based Mac machines, turns out currently there's a problem with the M1 chip and conda interaction. The solution is to use:

`CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n envName python=3.8.2`
followed by
`conda config --env --set subdir osx-64`

then on, you can use conda as usual.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `currently there's a problem with the M2 chip and conda interaction` -> I wouldn't call it a "problem". There simply is no installation candidate in the default channels or `conda-forge`. 3.8.2 was released before the first M1 (osx-arm64) machine was released

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer though

Comment: You're right - I meant to say M1, not M2 - I just edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.